# How to embed Base14 fonts using the PoDoFo library

Tags: pdf, podofo

I am using PoDoFo library to generate a PDF document. All fonts except Base14 ones (*"Courier", "Helvetica", "Times", "Symbol", "ZapfDingbats"*) are embedded. 
How to embed these 4 Base14 fonts?

Comment: You have to start by finding appropriate font files to embed: pdf libraries usually only bring along the metrics of those fonts, notre complete font files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `CreateFont()` function uses the `EFontCreationFlags::eFontCreationFlags_AutoSelectBase14` attribute (so it doesn't have to be given).

```
PoDoFo::PdfDocument *pDocument;
... 
pDocument->CreateFont("Times", false, false, false, 
    PoDoFo::PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalIdentityEncodingInstance(),
    PoDoFo::PdfFontCache::eFontCreationFlags_AutoSelectBase14
);
```

This attribute makes the function automatically check if the font is a Base14 one, and if it is, then PoDoFo doesn't embed the font. Use the PdfFontCache::eFontCreationFlags_None flag to embed the font.

```
PoDoFo::PdfDocument *pDocument;
... 
pDocument->CreateFont("Times", false, false, false,
    PoDoFo::PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalIdentityEncodingInstance(),
    PoDoFo::PdfFontCache::eFontCreationFlags_None
);
```